# SupportMapFragment and DrawerLayout in one AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android, google-maps

My hierarchy:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      <fragment "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line
#9: Duplicate id 0x7f0d007b, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
```

After commenting out map or navigation drawer app start working correctly.

How to make `SupportMapFragment` and `DrawerLayout` in one `Activity` and what is the reason for this exeption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Way :

Dependency section of my **build.gradle** :

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"      
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <fragment 
                 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                 android:id="@+id/map"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

             <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/add"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_maps_navigation"
                app:backgroundTint="#777"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/nav_container"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @user3871754 I have posted the structure see my answer below.

Comment: thanks, I am checking it, Can you add comment, what is wrtong with my hierarchy?